# SSH TAP tunnel & multicast groups

Tags: ssh, linux-networking, ssh-tunnel, multicast, tap

Is it possible to do UDP multicasting over an SSH TAP tunnel?

I have set up a TAP tunnel using SSH between my Ubuntu PC and a Raspberry Pi sitting in a remote office, using this command:

```
$ ssh -o Tunnel=ethernet -w 0:0 me@remotehost
$ sudo dhclient tap0
```

I have previously created tap interfaces on both sides of the link with the correct permissions for this to work without being logged in as root on either end.

This is enough that my local `tap0` interface can get an IP address on the remote network by DHCP.

But I have some software which uses UDP multicasting to find equipment installed on the remote network (essentially a Python script at this stage).  When I run this script on the Pi that is physically on the remote network, it works.  But when I run it on my PC with a TAP tunnel to the remote network, it doesn't.

Is it possible to do UDP multicasting over an SSH TAP tunnel?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind.  This didn't work because `dhclient` set a default route through the TAP tunnel.  `sudo route del default` and it all works.